# Ubuntu 15.10 - no login screen after installing/removing packages

Tags: 15.10

I have tried to install package `libepoxy0:i386` (I thought this can solve an error in one of application, nevermind).
I saw the question: `Do you want to continue?`, I hit `Y`, and then... When progress was `~22%` I saw that earlier in console there was an information:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required
```

with long list of packages... I remember that there was `Firefox` on this list and some packages with name containing `unity` or `gnome`. Then I stopped this operation and restarted Ubuntu, but now... I see only screen with Ubuntu logo and 5 flashing dots.

I tried to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and use the console, but then there is no login question.

I saved the output from the console (after I stopped removing/installing package) to the file and I'd like to paste it here (maybe could be helpful), but I saved it on a disk before restart and I don't even know how to open it, because I cannot run Ubuntu.

Can I do something different than reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: try turning off your computer then when you turn it back on immediately hold down the shift key. hopefully this will get you into the grub screen . .choose advanced options and then choose recovery mode.. in there there is an option for dpkg to fix broken packages .. try that and see if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the live boot mode from an installation disk or USB flash drive.  then mount the root partition and block devices.  thereafter, chroot to the mounted location and you can run apt-get install ubuntu-desktop and other missing packages.

if you have lvm volumes instead of plain old partitions (this isn't necessary on newer Ubuntu distributions. I think 14.04+):

```
apt-get install lvm2
vgchange -a y
```

Mount the Ubuntu root partition (lvm partitions are under /dev/mapper, otherwise they are /dev/sda[1-9])

```
mkdir /mnt/system
mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /mnt/system
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/system/boot
for i in /dev/pts /dev /proc /sys; do mount -B $i /mnt/system$i; done
chroot /mnt/system
```

first, make sure dependencies and broken packages are fixed:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Try to figure out what is missing or corrupt and (re)install it.

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```